# HTML Table with 2 rows. 1 Fixed height, 1 100%. Larger than window. Why?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>


    <style type="text/css">


    html, body, form, table, tbody, tr {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border-style: none;
    }

    tr#MainTitle
    {
        height: 70px;
    }

    div#test {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    /* If I remove the 100% here then the scrollbars are removed  and the cell still fills the window but the div no longer fills the cell. */

    td.MainMenu {
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="#" id="form1">
  <table id="Main"> 
    <tbody>

        <tr id="MainTitle">
            <td>Title</td>
        </tr>       

        <tr id="MainMenuRow">
            <td valign="top" class='MainMenu' id='MainMenu'><div id="test">Test</div></td>     
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

(edit) I've tried to simplify the issue. I have a table. I want the top title row to be fixed in size and the next content row to fill the remaining screen.

As I have it set up if the content cell is height:100% Then the page is larger than the window (by the size of the title row) yet if I switch this to auto the cell is the right size for the window but the contained div does not fill the cell.

Whats going on?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to acomplish with such layout? Cause there may be a better solution than using tables. But you should tell what exactly you want the layout to do.

Comment: Ok so I havent been entirely clear in my description but I have more understanding of what is going on now. Firstly this is a simplification of a legacy layout so I have no control over the table shape, the test div is where my content goes. As you say, Im using 70 px + 100% which is why its too big but I need to have content in the bottom cell and If I remove the 100% from the cell then the 100% height on the div degrades to auto, as per the css standards. Seems like a Catch-22 situation. I'm working in ie8 standards mode.

Comment: Check my answer again - i think that is exactly what you needed. Anyway - next time i suggest you use firefox + firebug - will make things much more simple for you to debug.

Comment: Again, unfortunately it doesn't work in standards mode, only quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

tr does not accept height attribute. You need to set that on td or th element. This code should do the work.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, form, table {height: 100%;width: 100%;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;border:0;}
    tr th {height:70px;}
    tr td {background-color: blue;position:relative;vertical-align:top;}
    .text {position:relative;height:100%;width:100%;background:yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="#" id="form1">
  <table id="Main" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><div class="text">Test</div></td>     
        </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does give the correct table layout but the containing div where you have 'Test' would not be able to fill the cell as its height would degrade to auto as its parent element has no assigned height.

Comment: I edited the answer - i thought you don't need the inside div. Check it now - the inside div fits nicely.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works in quirks mode. If you add the doctype to move to standards it no longer works.

Comment: Damn, forgot about dtd - was writing in notepad. Now this seems like an interesting thing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by the default margins on the BODY element in your code. You are specifying that the BODY should take up 100% of the available space, but by default, the BODY tag will add a margin to this, causing your elements to take up slightly more than 100% of the available screen space.

You can fix this by adding the following to your BODY style:

```
html, body, form {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the issue. The scrolling area is much larger and seems to be the size of the title row at the top.

Comment: What browser are you using? In Firefox this fixes the issue. IE has odd ways of dealing with box models, so you may be seeing different behaviour if you're using that.

Comment: It's simple what's going on: #MainTitle + td.MainMenu = 100% + 70px height that add at bottom.

Comment: I'm using ie8 but I just tested it in Firefox and its still there.